# SFINAE overload operator<< to call 'print' method if it exists

Tags: c++, sfinae

I've been trying to understand SFINAE and was trying to write a simple overloaded operator << that would call the 'print' method on any class that contains such a method.  I read through the answers on the question [Is it possible to write a template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence) and tried writing:

```
template<class T, class = decltype(void(std::declval<T>().print), std::true_type{})>
inline std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const T &obj) {
    obj.print(out); return out; }
```

and

```
template<class T, class = decltype(void(std::declval<T>().print(std::declval<std::ostream &>())), std::true_type{})>
inline std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const T &obj) {
    obj.print(out); return out; }
```

but this simply doesn't work -- the compiler seems to have no problem instantiating the template for any type, so gives slews of 'ambiguous overload' errors when I try to print things like string literals...

Comment: Why would you need such a method?  You should simply "rename" your `print()` functions to `operator <<` which is standard.

Comment: Unrelated, but there is no need to declare such template as `inline`; it will be implicit.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Doesn't work if `print` is virtual (the usual case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "function exists" expression is incorrect. Try this:

```
template <typename T,
          typename = decltype(
               void(std::declval<T>().print(std::declval<std::ostream&>())),
                    std::true_type{})>  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const T & obj)
{
    obj.print(out);
    return out;
}
```

You might also consider this alternative:

```
template <typename T>
auto operator<<(std::ostream & out, const T & obj)
     -> decltype(obj.print(out), (void)0, out)
{
    obj.print(out);
    return out;
}
```

Comment: The second version looks elegant but isn't there a problem if the return type of `print` has an overloaded operator `,`?  I'm not sure if casting to `void` could solve this.

Comment: @5gon12eder: It probably would; feel free to cast. Or just `(obj.print(out), static_cast<void>(0), os)`? Or `decltype(obj.print(out), throw 0, os)`.

Comment: The first one is the second (non-working) example I tried above.  The second alternative seems to work, however.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: As demonstrated, both examples work. Can you reproduce the error?

Comment: After including the first decl above, a simple `std::cout << "text string";` causes g++ 4.8.2 to give the error `ambiguous overload for 'operator<<'`

Comment: I take that back -- a trivial program with just `#include <iostream>`, either of my attempts, and a `cout << "string"` compiles ok.  So something else (some class declaration I have in my code) is needed to make gcc trigger an error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you've meant your second type parameter

```
class = decltype(void(std::declval<T>().print), std::true_type{})
```

to mean.  What is this supposed to evaluate to?

I think you can make it work by using the following.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T,
         typename = decltype(std::declval<const T>().print(std::cout))>
std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& out, const T& obj)
{
  obj.print(out);
  return out;
}

struct A
{
  void
  print(std::ostream& out) const
  {
    out << "A";
  }
};

int
main()
{
  A a {};
  std::cout << "And the winner is: " << a << std::endl;
}
```

It will correctly output `And the winner is: A` but there are probably some corner cases I've overlooked.

The expression

```
decltype(std::declval<const T>().print(std::cout))
```

will evaluate to the return type of the `print(std::ostream&) const` member function if such function is declared and a type error otherwise.

Comment: It's supposed to evalute to true type (and be ignored) if and only if the part before the comma evaluates to a valid pointer-to-method type (iff the `print` method exists)